# global_planner finds a path but is not able to find a valid trajectory

Tags: ros, navigation, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to use the global planner [global_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner).

It finds a path either in dijsktra or A* and changing the different parameters as this image shows

[image: sweet global path]

But then the robot stays still and (most of the times) I get this warning:

```
[ WARN] [1390404456.350870633, 3038.563000000]: Invalid Trajectory 0.000000, 0.000000, -0.300000, cost: -1.000000
```

until a fatal error appears, after 6 seconds:

```
[ERROR] [1390404456.403586383, 3038.611000000]: Aborting because a valid control could not be found. Even after executing all recovery behaviors
```

- Is there some parameter or remap missing in the [global_planner wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner)?
- Is there any example of the global_planner with a launch and yaml files?

Thanks in advance!

### Update

I found out that the global_plan publishes the poses from goal to origin whereas navfn publishes them from origin to goal.
I would say this is the problem that makes the robot stay still, I copy a couple of results:

oringin (x≅0) and goal (x≅1) of a path in **navfn**:

```
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -0.1
      y: -0.05
...
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.998614728451
      y: 0.0215734690428
```

oringin (x≅0) and goal (x≅1) of a path in **global_planner**:

```
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 1.0
      y: 0.0
...
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -0.25
      y: -0.05
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120786/global_planner-finds-a-path-but-is-not-able-to-find-a-valid-trajectory/) by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 843 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pushing a patch but I've just made it work reversing the vector of the plan.

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/global_planner/src/planner_core.cpp#L329

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2014-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1